# conflict or error with richfaces-component-ui 4.0

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x

when I add richfaces-component-ui4.0.jar to my artifact I get this error
I use jboss ap7

what this error means ?
i think it's about some conflict

```
14:59:53,333 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed to define class org.richfaces.renderkit.ComponentControlBehaviorRenderer in Module "deployment.EAR_ear_exploded.ear:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/richfaces/renderkit/ComponentControlBehaviorRenderer (Module "deployment.EAR_ear_exploded.ear:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:527) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfAnnotationProcessor.deploy(JsfAnnotationProcessor.java:115)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/render/ClientBehaviorRenderer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.render.ClientBehaviorRenderer from [Module "deployment.EAR_ear_exploded.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA]
    ... 21 more

14:59:53,347 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."EAR_ear_exploded.ear".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EAR_ear_exploded.ear".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "EAR_ear_exploded.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:123) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018045: Failed to load annotated class: org.richfaces.renderkit.ComponentControlBehaviorRenderer
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfAnnotationProcessor.deploy(JsfAnnotationProcessor.java:117)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    ... 5 more

14:59:53,568 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "EAR_ear_exploded.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EAR_ear_exploded.ear\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EAR_ear_exploded.ear\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"EAR_ear_exploded.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018045: Failed to load annotated class: org.richfaces.renderkit.ComponentControlBehaviorRenderer"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerFacadeImp.ValidatorFactory Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerFacadeImp.Validator Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserFacadeImp.Validator Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserDAO.Validator Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeDAO.ValidatorFactory Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerDAO.Validator Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeDAO.Validator Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserFacadeImp.ValidatorFactory Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserFacadeImp]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeFacadeImp.Validator Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeFacadeImp]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EAR_ear_exploded.ear\".\"EJB.jar\".INSTALL Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserDAO.ValidatorFactory Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserDAO]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EAR_ear_exploded.ear\".\"WEB.war\".INSTALL Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerDAO.ValidatorFactory Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerDAO]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeFacadeImp.ValidatorFactory Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeFacadeImp]"]}
14:59:53,576 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerDAO (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerDAO.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerDAO.Validator] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerFacadeImp (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerFacadeImp.Validator, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerFacadeImp.ValidatorFactory] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeDAO (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeDAO.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeDAO.Validator] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeFacadeImp (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeFacadeImp.Validator, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeFacadeImp.ValidatorFactory] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserDAO (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserDAO.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserDAO.Validator] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserFacadeImp (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserFacadeImp.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserFacadeImp.Validator] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."EAR_ear_exploded.ear".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."EAR_ear_exploded.ear".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "EAR_ear_exploded.ear"

14:59:53,613 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EJB.jar in 38ms
14:59:53,626 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment WEB.war in 52ms
14:59:53,666 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EAR_ear_exploded.ear in 95ms
14:59:53,668 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerDAO (new available)
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerFacadeImp (new available)
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeDAO (new available)
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.ServerTypeFacadeImp (new available)
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserDAO (new available)
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EAR_ear_exploded.EJB.UserFacadeImp (new available)
```

Comment: Are you including any JSF API or implementation libraries in your deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess was true and it is a conflict
jboss AP has lots of libraries for it's own
and when I added libraries related to jsf some conflicted happend .
the best way is to using maven for dependencies , you can easily say which dependency is for compile or which is for developing and ...
an other way is when you add library to IDE specify that just use it for developing and not for run time or compiling

and a bad way is to delete libraries that made conflict , from JBOSS AP